# Convert Decimal Number to char array of it's binary representation:

Tags: c, binary, char

1. How would I write code in C to assign a decimal number's binary representation to a char variable?

   ```
   \\ x is the value of the decimal integer
   \\ y is length of the binary representation

   {
   binary[33] = {0};

   while(x!=0){
       binary[y] = (x%2)+'0';
       y--;
       x/=2;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: If lowest bit is set is much faster to do `number & 1` instead of `number % 2`.

Comment: @tilz0R Any halfway reasonable compiler of the last 10-20 years will convert the modulo to a masking opeartion **if it yields the same result**.

Comment: @tilz0R It is pretty much the same. Chances the compiler will generate the same code.

Comment: Read [ask], provide a [mcve] and a **specific** question.

Comment: Note, this question has been answered dozens of time on S.O. Simply checking the **Related** post on the right side of your browser window will disclose several. Searching will disclose many many more.

Comment: @tilz0R It's about 1,000,000 times more important for this poster to figure out a way of solving his problem that works and makes sense, than it is to worry about microoptimizations.  (And, in any case, as Olaf and Eugene already pointed out, the compiler is in a much better position to be performing optimizations like that anyway.  Most compilers do, and if you're somehow using one that doesn't, either you don't care about efficiency, or you should be looking for a better compiler.)  Also, you said "much faster" -- have you measured it?

Comment: I guess I asked wrong. I don't see anything here that really answers my question. I'll have to take David's advice and dig more.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of scanning bits in number is to start with MSB bit of input number and to proceed to the LSB bit. When first `1` is detected, start printing/saving/whatever, even if `0` is later detected.

This is now example, which will print bits of your number, starting to print when it reaches first `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "limits.h"

int main() {
    unsigned int num = 10;
    int y = 0, i;

    for (i = sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (num & (1U << i)) {
            printf("1");
            y++;
        } else if (y) {
            printf("0");
            y++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output for `num = 10`: `1010`

If you want to store your result to array, replace `printf` statements with something similar to: `outputBuffer[y] = '1'` or `'0'`

Comment: `putchar ('1')` or `putchar ('0`)` instead of the variadic `printf`?

Comment: Pedantically, on rare machines where `unsigned` is padded, `sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT - 1` is a problem, yet good enough for learner code.  An alternative uses `unsigned mask = UINT_MAX - UINT_MAX/2` and then `mask >>= 1;`

Comment: It's also worth noting that the representation of a negative number (e.g. `unsigned int num = -5;`) will be its *two-compliment* storage format *sign-extended* to the width of `num` on machines utilizing *two-compliment* (all x86 variants)